# MySQL - storing 162 million rows in 1 table as the result of an IFNULL query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, storage

I'm working on a legacy web application which uses a MySQL (5.5.65-MariaDB) database which is hosted on a server running CentOS Linux 7.7.1908.

The application is a database of chemical substances and at the moment contains approx 270,000 substances. This number will grow over time but historically - over the last 3 years - only around 10,000 per year have been added.

Every substance has a unique ID and name which is stored in 1 table called `substances`. The structure is as follows:

```
> DESCRIBE substances;
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(1500)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So this table currently contains approx 270,000 rows: 1 per substance.

When a user views 1 individual substance in the application, it shows a table which is split into 2 columns. An example of this is as follows (I've removed the actual data since it's a proprietary application):

[image]

The rows on the left ("Regulatory List A ... C") are stored in a table called `displays`. The information in the rows on the right is stored in a table called `display_substances`. These tables have a 1:1 relationship: one `displays.id` relates to one `display_substances.display_id`. The structure of the tables is as follows:

```
> DESCRIBE displays;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(127)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

> DESCRIBE display_substances;
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| substance_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

On the screenshot, there are 2 rows which say "Not Listed ^". This is shown to the user when there is no `display_substances.value` for the substance (`display_substances.substance_id`) assigned to the Display (`display_substances.display_id`). In simple terms this means there is no data about that row stored in our database. So on the screenshot above there is only 1 `display_substances.value` - the one containing the "Lorem ipsum dolor..." text. The other 2 rows which have "Not Listed ^" **do not** have any rows in `display_substances`.

The query to generate this involves using an `IFNULL ... GROUP_CONCAT` condition which puts the text "Not Listed ^" in, if there is no corresponding row. The query is as follows:

```
-- ds.substance_id = 1 is an example (substances.id = 1)

SELECT 
d.id, 
IFNULL(
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM display_substances `ds` 
        WHERE `ds`.`display_id` = `d`.`id`
        AND ds.substance_id = 1 
        GROUP BY `ds`.`display_id`
    ), "Not Listed ^"
) `display_value` FROM displays `d` 
HAVING `display_value` = "Not Listed ^" -- This condition is explained further down 
ORDER BY d.id ASC
```

### The problem

The `displays` table contains approx 890 rows, all of which are shown for every substance. Currently the `display_substances` table contains approx 1.8 million rows. However, this is because it **does not** contain rows for anything which is "Not Listed ^".

We have a project where we need to identify and log anything which is "Not Listed ^". The SQL given above generates exactly what we need (this is the purpose of the `HAVING` condition).

The SQL above executes in approx 1 second per substance. From some tests I've done on 100 substances, about 600 rows come back as "Not Listed ^" for any 1 individual substance.

This gives me 2 problems:

1. 600 rows for 270,000 substances would result in 162,000,000 records to log.
2. The time taken to execute this is 1 second * 270,000 substances which is approx 3 days (270k seconds).

The storage for the log - i.e. where we would `INSERT` rows to log this - is a table which is as follows:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| substance_id              | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| display_id                | int(5)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created                   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified                  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm not convinced that I'm approaching this in the right way, and would appreciate advice on points (1) and (2) above.

Point (2) is of less concern because we would be able to run the process through `crontab` in the background and there's no time constraint of how quickly this needs to work.

The bigger concern is point (1) which is whether storing ~160 million rows in a table is really a good idea (bearing in mind our biggest table so far is 1.8 million rows). I anticipate the storage for that table would be at least 12 Gb. Is this excessive for a table, or is this normal in applications when you need to store such volumes of data?

How do people deal with this type of scenario?

Comment: Rewrite your query which uses correlated subquery, to LEFT JOIN, for displaying the output like on the screenstot. Use WHERE NOT EXISTS for selecting a list of "Not listed" rows.

Comment: Replace DESCRIBE (which is unusable) with CREATE TABLE for your tables (including all existing indexes). Create modelling data (3-10 rows per table is enough) and post this as INSERT INTO. Or create online fiddle with the above data.

Comment: 162M won't fit in `MEDIUMINT`; suggest `INT UNSIGNED`.